# Magento 2 | Varnish cache pages per session

Tags: magento2, session, varnish

We have a magento 2.2.6 shop, with 20k products. We use varnish for fpc. It is configured properly, and we can verify by visiting a page two times. The second time the ttf is really low. Problem is that in another session, the page is not cached so on first request ttf is really big.

Notice that we use the default exported vcl for varnish 5. We had another problem, while implementing magento vcl and we had to remove the health_check.php from vcl.

Comment: For the record, we solved it by using this solution : https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/262246/magento-2-varnish-caching-per-instance?rq=1

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Magento 2 Varnish caching per instance](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/262246/magento-2-varnish-caching-per-instance)